# Filter / sorting Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
spt_curr_A = ["acb|123|N", "bca|234|N", "dcs_abc|134|Y", "abc|432|N", "def_bca|243|Y"]

for (var i = 0; i < spt_curr_A.length; i++){
   sl = spt_curr_A[i].split("|");

   console.log("Split: " + sl);
}
```

Once it is split, I only want the the ones with "`N`" to be display as `sl`. I have tried several different ways with no luck.

Comment: `spt_curr_A.filter(s => s.endsWith('N'))` before you loop or print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Loop through the array and check if element of array contains `|N` at end using [`str.endsWidth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith). Below is working code:

```js
var spt_curr_A = ["acb|123|N", "bca|234|N", "dcs_abc|134|Y", "abc|432|N", "def_bca|243|Y"];

var new_array = [];

for (var i in spt_curr_A) {
  if (spt_curr_A[i].endsWith("|N")) {
    new_array.push(spt_curr_A[i])
  }
}

console.log(new_array);
```

**Option 2:**

You can check if in `sl` array `element` at index `2` is `N` or not like below:

```js
var spt_curr_A = ["acb|123|N", "bca|234|N", "dcs_abc|134|Y", "abc|432|N", "def_bca|243|Y"]

for (var i = 0; i < spt_curr_A.length; i++) {
  sl = spt_curr_A[i].split("|");
  if (sl[2] === "N") {
    console.log("Split: " + sl);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Doug glad to help you.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays have methods which mean you don't always need to iterate over them manually in order to get data from them. Methods such as `map` and `filter` return an array, so can be chained together.

Working with arrays in this way makes code easier to read and adjust. In the example I give below, I use `map` and `filter` to get only the data which is useful to us. Then, `forEach` allows us to iterate the remaining items and log them to the console.

If you're interested in learning more about array methods, [this article](https://medium.com/@joomiguelcunha/learn-map-filter-and-reduce-in-javascript-ea59009593c4) is a good place to start.

Your original code could be adjusted to make a similar check:

```js
spt_curr_A = ["acb|123|N", "bca|234|N", "dcs_abc|134|Y", "abc|432|N", "def_bca|243|Y"]

for (var i = 0; i < spt_curr_A.length; i++){
   sl = spt_curr_A[i].split("|");
   
   if (sl[2] === 'N') {
    console.log("Split: " + sl);
   }   
}
```

But you may find it easier to work with code that uses `map` and `filter` instead of a for loop:

```js
spt_curr_A = ["acb|123|N", "bca|234|N", "dcs_abc|134|Y", "abc|432|N", "def_bca|243|Y"]

spt_curr_A
  .map(item => item.split('|'))
  .filter(item => item[2] === 'N')
  .forEach(item => console.log(`Split ${item}`))
```

Comment: You should really expand on your answer. e.g. Explain what the OP did wrong and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using the function `Array.prototype.filter`.

*Assuming every element has three sections (two pipes).*

```js
let spt_curr_A = ["acb|123|N", "bca|234|N", "dcs_abc|134|Y", "abc|432|N", "def_bca|243|Y"],
    fn = (s) => s.split("|").pop() === "N",
    filtered = spt_curr_A.filter(fn);

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about Array.includes()?

```
spt_curr_A = ["acb|123|N", "bca|234|N", "dcs_abc|134|Y", "abc|432|N", "def_bca|243|Y"]

for (var i = 0; i < spt_curr_A.length; i++){
   sl = spt_curr_A[i].split("|");

    if(sl.includes("N"))
    {
        console.log("Split: " + sl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do filter first and then you can do any operatin

```js
let spt_curr_A = ["acb|123|N", "bca|234|N", "dcs_abc|134|Y", "abc|432|N", "def_bca|243|Y"]

spt_curr_A = spt_curr_A.filter((str) => {
 return str.indexOf('|N') !== -1
});
spt_curr_A= spt_curr_A.splice("|")
console.log(spt_curr_A)
```